# Тег textarea - добавления редактора

Tags: html, html5, css

Здраствуйте. У меня по ходу работы возникла вот такка проблема. У меня есть форма в которой есть тег textarea. Мне нужно прикрепить как то к нему небольшой редактор или что то в этом роде. Тойсть чтобы можна было выранивать текст, делать жирным, курсивом. ...и т.д. что то похожое как сдесь на форуме. Буду очень благодарен если кто поможет советом как это можна реализовать. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Выбираете любой понравившийся [wysiwyg редактор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), читаете документацию и подключаете соответствующим образом. Обзор некоторых таких редакторов, можно [посмотреть в этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129262/).